# What is the "application configuration file" in a rebar3 app?

Tags: erlang

The [inets httpd server docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_server.html) say,

> The following is to be put in the Erlang node ***application
>   configuration file*** to start an HTTP server at application startup:
>
> ```
>   [{inets, [{services, [{httpd, [{proplist_file,
>          "/var/tmp/server_root/conf/8888_props.conf"}]},
>         {httpd, [{proplist_file,
>          "/var/tmp/server_root/conf/8080_props.conf"}]}]}]}].
> ```

Where does that go in an app created by rebar3?

The [OTP Application docs](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html) say,

> 7.8  Configuring an Application
>
> An application can be configured using configuration parameters. These
>   are a list of {Par,Val} tuples specified by a key env in the .app
>   file:
>
> ```
> {application, ch_app,
>  [{description, "Channel allocator"},
>   {vsn, "1"},
>   {modules, [ch_app, ch_sup, ch3]},
>   {registered, [ch3]},
>   {applications, [kernel, stdlib, sasl]},
>   {mod, {ch_app,[]}},
>   {env, [{file, "/usr/local/log"}]}
>  ]}.
> ```
>
> Par is to be an atom. Val is any term.

That seems to suggest that you create environment variables with `{Name, Value}` tuples.  However, the required code specified in the httpd server docs does not seem to be in that format.

Comment: Check the section about sys.config on the [erlang config docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/config.html#id150927) and the [Configuring an Application](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id82446) section of the docs about Applications.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop this into the sys.config file which is in config folder of your release. If you have anything there already, it will be in the format of:

```
[
 {some_app, [{env_var, value},{...}]},
 {another_app, [{env_var, value},{...}]},
 % add here without outer[]...,
 {kernel,
  [{distributed, [{app_name, 5000,
  ['node@10.0.211.153', 'node_failover@10.8.222.15']}]}, 
  {sync_nodes_mandatory, []},
  {sync_nodes_optional, ['node_failover@10.8.222.15']},
  {sync_nodes_timeout, 5000}]}
]
```

Comment: *sys.config file which is in config folder of your application* -- rebar3 didn't create a config directory for me, nor do I see a config directory mentioned anywhere in "Chapter 9: Applications" in the book "Designing for Scalability with Erlang/OTP (Cesarini, Vinoski)".  I tried creating a config directory and a sys.config file, but when I do `$ rebar3 shell` and then try to send a request to the inets httpd server, I get a "connection refused" error.

Comment: rebar3 makes the folder only when you use rebar3 new release release_name. if you used rebar3 new app app_name it will not make the config folder and files.

Comment: alternatively, you can put this directly inside the application config file, usually in the src folder your_app.app.src. add {env, [{Key, Val}]} see  http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-otp-applications .

Comment: when you use application:get_env(AppName, Key). it will get them from both files, so rebar3 probably writes it to the same place.